# Mitzvah and Connection

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah

Heard from someone that מצוה, *commandment*, is associated with the Aramaic word צוותא, *connection* or *togetherness*.

In addition,  [Rabbi Moshe Zeldman](http://www.aish.com/sp/ph/What-is-a-Mitzvah.html) says, "The word Mitzvah is often translated as commandment... The Rabbis point out that the word within mitzvah is *tzav* which means *connection*."

Does anyone know where the source for these can be found?

Comment: @Chiddushei_Torah please provide Aramaic TaNaKH passages that uses צוותא

Comment: Anybody here speaks Arabic? It says in the following online definition that "Arabic wasa" (meaning "he bound, united") is "related" to the word mitzvah. Just want to know if anybody sees a similarity of letters of mitzvah to wasa? I don't see a similary, unless there is a transposition that took place: wasa from mitswa, perhaps.

[mitzvah (n.)
Jewish rabbinical commandment, 1640s, from Hebrew mitzwah "commandment, precept," from base of tziwwah "he commanded," related to Arabic wasa "he bound, united."]
source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/mitzvah#etymonline_v_17352

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shlah writes [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37856_490.pdf) in Yoma:

> ולשון מצוה - צוותא, כענין שאמרו (ברכות ו ב) כל העולם לא נברא אלא לצוות לזה.

Additionally, the Sfas Emmes writes this (Parshas Eikev: 632):

> ומצוה לשון צותא וחיבור כמ"ש במ"א

Comment: Other Chassidic sources such as the Meor Einayim state this as well.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you very much! Secondly, can you send me link for the Shlah and the Sefas Emes that you quoted to me?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah The Sh'lah is [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37856_490.pdf#xml=http://hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=490&hilite=f62992f2-add6-47ce-ad77-8f7a3fe5680b&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) on the first line of the second paragraph.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I cant find the Sfas Emmes on Hebrewbooks (it isnt OCRed yet) you can see the text on the online Bar Ilan (dont get your hopes up, it is only a teaser to get you to pay for a full version) by entering the words of the Sfas Emmes [here](http://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=advancedSearch!yes). you will need to make an account (free) to view the whole text. Even that will need to be refreshed every ~30 seconds.

Comment: @mevaqesh please provide a rough translation for your above two line answer from Shlah and Sefas Emes.

Answer (score 0):

Chabad.org's "[What Happened At Sinai](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/154220)" writes:

> The word mitzvah (מצוה) and the word tzavta (צותא), meaning “together”, share the same root.

Chabad.org's source given is "*Likkutei Torah, Parshas Bechukosai 45c*"

I also found the same [teaching](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rx0vAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22tefillin%22+aryeh+kaplan+%22bind+ourselves%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=++%22bind+ourselves%22) in [*Tefillin*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879016060) written by Rav Aryeh Kaplan ZTZ"L:

> "[…] The word mitzvah comes from a root meaning 'to bind'. Through the physical act of doing a mitzvah, we literally bind ourselves to G-d." (R. Aryeh Kaplan, Tefillin, OU/NCSY Publications, 2007, p. 44)

Comment: please provide Aramaic TaNaKH passages that uses צותא